# How to change and Work on a selected year database and create new database on every year

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I am working on an Accounting project using C#/.NET,Libraries,Reportings,etc 
and MS-SQL Server. so when a running financial period is closed on every year, example 
(30july2017---30july2018), 
I want to transfer all the data, all the transactions records of that year in a new database(you can say a new copy 
of that database), and save all that record in a drive for the previous long 
term evidence purposes. and create New Database for new financial year period and process new transactions etc.
 my basic Login UI consist of few things,
username (text)
pasword(text)
financial year Dropdown("2016-2017","2017-2018").

when I login Using 2017-2018, Database is selected to the newly created and 
perform transactions into this. But if I go Back Period (2016-2017) then It 
should not allow any EDIT in that Database.

the lookup of my description and the desire answer is based on this. 
not a UI Code is enough but SQL creating Database using this UI will be the answer for which I am finding here.

any one who can help me on this issue,

Comment: The database is a MDF file and the log file LDF.  So you can Deattach by right clicking the database in SQL Server Management Studio (do not need an admin).  Then copy the MDF and LDF to archive.  Then reattach in SSMS as a query : CREATE DATABASE [<database_name>]
ON
(NAME = <database_name>,
    FILENAME = ‘<full path and database file name>’ )
FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG

Where:
<database_name> = the name you want to appear inside SQL for the DB.  It is suggested that the following convention be used:

Comment: What will you do about transactions that span over two years? Like a debit in July 2018 that has a credit in August 2019?

Comment: @alroc is correct.  This sounds like a really bad idea, especially when it comes to reporting over 1 or more years. Your permissions on what data can be edited can be put in at an application level.

Comment: IMHO this really is a widely-scoped question of "how do I design accounting software with this particular feature?" and as such is too broad to be answered here. You have a **lot** to consider with doing this data separation & movement and when all is said and done, I think you'll find that it's not practical to do this and instead you're better off keeping everything in a single database and implementing controls and audit trails changing historical data.

Comment: @Moo-Juice excellent point, I hadn't even considered the reporting aspect, despite having to deal with it regularly myself :)

Comment: @alroc when year closing Debit and credit is 0 if some remain so then a new entry is made in term of "journal voucher entries"  in new database use that amount in new year and use further.

Answer (score 0):

from the Question, I can tell that you are handling accounts kind of data database like on closing one database some amount will be added to opening is next year and so forth that can be handled on application-level but as for creating the database, you can just simply call a stored procedure. here is a Procedure that might help.

```
    create PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateNewCompany]
    @CompName as varchar(max) ,--  for create New Company
    @BackupFilePath as varchar(max) -- Backup file path for Which Company DB is a copy for a new company
    As
    BEGIN 
    DECLARE @COL1 VARCHAR(256),@COL2 VARCHAR(256) -- Filename for backup    
    DECLARE @Lgfilenm1 VARCHAR(256) -- LogicalFilename for backup   
    DECLARE @Lgfilenm2 VARCHAR(256) -- LogicalFilename for backup   
    DECLARE @RestorePath VARCHAR(256)  -- PhysicalFilename for backup

    DECLARE @i int 
    set @i = 0

    --- Make Temp Table 
    create table TmtNewDB ( LogicalName nvarchar(128),PhysicalName nvarchar(260),Type char(1),FileGroupName nvarchar(128),Size numeric(20,0)
    ,MaxSize numeric(20,0),Fileid tinyint,CreateLSN numeric(25,0),DropLSN numeric(25, 0),UniqueID uniqueidentifier,ReadOnlyLSN numeric(25,0),
    ReadWriteLSN numeric(25,0),BackupSizeInBytes bigint,SourceBlocSize int,FileGroupId int,LogGroupGUID uniqueidentifier,
    DifferentialBaseLSN numeric(25,0),DifferentialBaseGUID uniqueidentifier,IsReadOnly bit,IsPresent bit)

    insert TmtNewDB 
    EXEC ('restore filelistonly from disk = ''' + @BackupFilePath + '''')
    declare @a varchar(max),@posi int,@le int,@file varchar(max)
    DECLARE db_newdbb CURSOR FOR
    select LogicalName,PhysicalName from TmtNewDB

        OPEN db_newdbb  
        FETCH NEXT FROM db_newdbb INTO @COL1,@COL2 

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0    
        BEGIN 
                if @i=0 
                begin
                    set @Lgfilenm1=@COL1
                    set @posi  = CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(@COL2))
                    set @RestorePath=left(@COL2,len(@COL2)- @posi +1 )
                end
                else if @i=1 
                begin
                    set @Lgfilenm2 = @COL1
                end
        set @i = @i + 1
        FETCH NEXT FROM db_newdbb INTO @COL1,@COL2 
        END  

        CLOSE db_newdbb  
        DEALLOCATE db_newdbb

    declare @sql varchar(max)

     set @sql= 'RESTORE DATABASE  ' + @CompName + ' FROM  DISK = ''' + @BackupFilePath + ''' WITH  FILE = 1,
        MOVE N''' + @Lgfilenm1 + ''' TO N''' + @RestorePath+ @CompName + '.mdf' + ''',  
        MOVE N''' + @Lgfilenm2 + ''' TO N''' + @RestorePath+  @CompName + '_Log.ldf' + ''''
    -- print @sql
    -- @CompName check Company file already is created or not
    IF (EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE ('[' + name + ']' = @CompName OR name = @CompName)))
    begin
    print 'New Company Already Created------->newdbb'
    end
    else
    begin
    exec (@sql)
    print 'New Company Created Successfully------->newdbb'
    end

    END
```